# How do I draw graphs in the in asp core.net program?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, graph

I Want to create Graph from database in my project.
like this:
[image]

which database better for my project?
elastic  database?

Is there a framework for drawing graphs in the in asp core.net program ?

Comment: Can this help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/graph-introduction

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free plugin to achieve this requirement, I recommend using `canvas` to achieve this drawing function.

I have download one and test in my local, it works well. When we finish drawing, we can save the drawing content in base64 format and store it in any database. You can search for the keywords canvas + jquery + editor.

Related Links for you:
[jQuery Signature Plugin Demo Page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Touch-enabled-Signature-Plugin-with-jQuery-Canvas/)

[image]

**If you want the data of each circle related to the data in the database, I still recommend you to search for chart-related products, such as ECharts.**

Demo:  https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graphgl-large-internet&gl=1&theme=dark